# C# Adding a value from Windows Form Application to Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export

Hello and thank you for taking your time to read this! I have a small problem with my C# Windows Form application. Basically I have a register which registers employees for each day, whether they're sick/late or present etc...

**The problem**

When you select a value for each employee once (Combo box item), it works fine! It successfully adds the value to the excel document and saves it!

But when you select a value more than twice, it sometimes doesn't add the value to the excel document correctly.

In the picture, only Authorised Holiday shows up multiple times. Whereas, Sick doesn't show up at all.

[image: Application]

**What I have tried**

- Removing switch statement (Didn't work)

**Code:**

```
            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(Application.StartupPath + "/Excel Documents/2017 - holiday and sickness planner.xlsx");
            x = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
            userRange = x.UsedRange;

            int cell = 5; // Starts adding values at cell 5

            for (int i = 0; i < Classes.Employees.EmployeeList.Count; i++)
            {
                string stateValue = RegisterDGV.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value.ToString();
                string symbol = string.Empty;

                switch (stateValue)
                {
                    case "/ - Present":
                        symbol = string.Empty;
                        break;
                    case "S - Sick":
                        symbol = "S";
                        break;
                    case "HD - Half day holiday":
                        symbol = "HD";
                        break;
                    case "UP - Unpaid":
                        symbol = "UP";
                        break;
                    case "M - Maternity":
                        symbol = "M";
                        break;
                    case "T - Training":
                        symbol = "T";
                        break;
                    case "EH - Emergency Holiday":
                        symbol = "EH";
                        break;
                    case "H - Holiday":
                        symbol = "H";
                        break;
                    case "L - Late":
                        symbol = "L";
                        break;
                    case "A - Absent":
                        symbol = "A";
                        break;
                    case "AH - Authorised Holiday":
                        symbol = "AH";
                        break;
                }
                x.Range[String.Format("EO{0}", cell)].Value = symbol;
                cell++;
            }
            sheet.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            excel.Quit();
```

Each case represents each combox box item and then is narrowed down to just a symbol or characters.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Maybe your "sick" value isn't an exact match to the term in your switch block?

Comment: Instead of a switch statement, you can try using a dictionary with TryGetValue, it's relatively easy to get started with. You can use the strings as keys and out a string value for your purposes. Looking at your code, it may just be that the strings do not match exactly.

Comment: There must be something else going on after this code. If you have traced the code through this “switch” case statement and observed that the excel cell is getting set to the proper value, then something else is going on after this code. Have you traced the “switch” statement? I copy/pasted the "switch" case code and it appears to work as expected.